# LINQ is incredibly slow when performs query on small tables

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I'm trying to perform a simple query from a table that have 1K-2K records, and for some reason it takes more than 10 seconds.
The structure of the query is:

```
        using (context)
        {
            context.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

            foreach (Object _object in _objectSet)
            { 
                foreach (QueryFilter _filter in _fList)
                {  
                    try
                    {
                        Object2 object2 = precompiledQuery(context, _filter.var1, _filter.var2, _filter.var3, _filter.var4);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    { 
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The outer object list is the result of another query.
QueryFilters are custom object that specify values for WHERE statements, i think that it's equivalent to use a nested IN statement in SQL.

Precompiled query takes from 4-5 milliseconds (when it match a record) to 30-60 milliseconds (when it returns null).

Do you notice something wrong?

EDIT:

- objectSet size range between 10-200 elements
- filterList size range between 1-3 elements
- precompiledQuery is terminated with a `Single()` call, so it return a record
- It's not a shared context, I've created that context just for this operation

EDIT2:

```
    public static Func<LinqToSqlDataContext, int, int, bool, string, int, string, Action>
    GetRelativeAction =
    CompiledQuery.Compile((LinqToSqlDataContext db, int IDhand, int idp, bool isHero, string street, int br, string action) => (from r in dm.Actions
                                                                                                                             where (r.IDH == IDhand &&  r.Street.CompareTo(street)==0 && 
                                                                                                                             r.BetRound == br && r.Action1.CompareTo(action)==0 && r.Hero == isHero)
                                                                                                                             select r).Single());
```

Comment: Do you have indexes in place?

Comment: Yes! But in my opinion the problem is strictly related with my LINQ code, i've tried to query with pure SQL from SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO and query was very very fast, at least 10 time faster.

Comment: How big is your objectset? How many filters are in fList? What exactly is precompiledQuery doing? (returning an IQueryable? or does it evaluate the query?) And finally are you using a shared context?

Comment: "30-60 milliseconds when it searches everything" is pretty fast eh? Whether it's reasonably fast for what it is doing is another matter.

Comment: If precompiledQuery performs the query then you are performing a simple query a number of times, the number of times it is being performed would be helpful here.

Comment: Additional informations are under the label EDIT

Comment: If you believe that your issue is in your LINQ queries, why don't you show your LINQ queries?  You've only shown a nested for each loop.  There's nothing inherently wrong with a nested for each loop.